# MySQL not starting in Xampp?

Tags: server, mysql, xampp

I'm using Ubuntu 21.10 & Xammp 8.1.4. Apache web server & ProFTPD servers are running well. I have problems with MySQL server that is not running:

```
root@user-Inspiron-7386:~# /opt/lampp/lampp start
Starting XAMPP for Linux 8.1.4-1...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL.../opt/lampp/share/xampp/xampplib: line 22: netstat: command not found
ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD.../opt/lampp/share/xampp/xampplib: line 22: netstat: command not found
ok.
root@user-Inspiron-7386:~# /opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server: 263: kill: No such process
```

Does anyone know any methods how to solve it ??

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because XAMPP requires the `net-tools` package, which contains `netstat`. To install the package, do this:

```
sudo apt install net-tools
```

Alternatively, it would be *really* beneficial if you did not use XAMPP on Linux. XAMPP was created for Windows. Linux already has excellent support for Apache, MySQL, PHP, PostgreSQL, and whatnot. XAMPP knowledge generally cannot be transferred to Linux, whereas knowing how the actual packages work will allow you to solve problems on many other platforms.